# Countable normal space with every singleton closed is not connected

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a countable infinite set. Show there doesn't exist a topology on $X$ such that $X$ is normal, connected and every singleton subset of $X$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: If $X$ is a countable connected space, then every continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending bof's comment:

If $X$ is countable and connected and $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is continous then $f$ is constant, because $\mbox{im}(f)$ is a connected and countable (possibly finite) subset of $\mathbb{R}$. The only subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with such properties are singletons.

Now if $X$ is normal with closed singletons then pick $a, b\in X$, $a\neq b$ and define $f:\{a, b\}\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(a)=0$, $f(b)=1$. Obviously $f$ is continous and since $X$ is normal then [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) applies: $f$ can be extended to $F:X\to\mathbb{R}$. But $F$ is not constant. Contradiction.

Comment: Correct (+1) but instead of Tietze's extension theorem you could just use Urysohn's lemma (which is usually proved as a step along the way to Tietze's extension theorem).